# How to get cell value after clicking on datagrid row

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I have a C# WPF DataGrid to list information about documents (e.g. invoices).
The user is able to select one row in the Datagrid. After double-clicking the row I need to access a specific cell value (docId).

Unfortunately I don't know how to access the correct datarow behind the selected datagrid row.

I can access following values from my grid:

```
dataGrid_docs.selectedValue
dataGrid_docs.selectedItem
```

...

selected Value is not the answer to my problem because the user ist clicking any row, not always the correct column.

```
        // Create a new DataTable.    
        DataTable custTable = new DataTable("Customers");


        // Create docId column 
            dtColumn = new DataColumn();
            dtColumn.DataType = typeof(string);
            dtColumn.ColumnName = "docId";
            custTable.Columns.Add(dtColumn);

        // Create createDate column 
            dtColumn = new DataColumn();
            dtColumn.DataType = typeof(string);
            dtColumn.ColumnName = "createDate";
            custTable.Columns.Add(dtColumn);


        dtSet = new DataSet();
        dtSet.Tables.Add(custTable);



        foreach (var doc in docs)
        {
            myDataRow = custTable.NewRow();
            foreach (var attribute in ecoDmsAttributes)
            {                    
                myDataRow["docId"] = "123"
                myDataRow["createDate"] = "2019-08-27"
            }
            custTable.Rows.Add(myDataRow);
        }


        dataGrid_docs.ItemsSource = custTable.DefaultView;




    private void DataGrid_docs_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView docid = dataGrid_docs.SelectedItem;

        txt_Debug.Text = "Clicked on docId: " + docid.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can retrive values from DataRowView by column name, e.g. `dataRowView["docId"]`

```
private void DataGrid_docs_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)dataGrid_docs.SelectedItem;

    txt_Debug.Text = "Clicked on docId: " + dataRowView["docId"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try the DataGridView's CellContentClick event. There, you can access `e.RowIndex` and `e.ColumnIndex` to get the value of the cell clicked. You may have to combine that somehow with another method though to see if it was a double click.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be most the way there:

```
DataRowView docid = dataGrid_docs.SelectedItem;
```

A `DataRowView` has a [.Row property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowview.row?view=netframework-4.8) that will retrieve the underlying datarow that the view is passing through:

```
DataRow ro = (dataGrid_docs.SelectedItem as DataRowView)?.Row;
var docid = ro["docId"]; //returns object. Use cast (string) or .ToString()
```

There's probably little practical difference between this and ash's answer, though I interpreted your requirement as wanting the DataRow itself, rather than the values in the row as exposed by the view

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you just should try harder before asking on stackoverflow. It was pretty simple calling:

```
            DataRowView docid = dataGrid_docs.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

            txt_Debug.Text = "Clicked on: " + docid.Row["DocID"];
```